# Drawing with UIGraphics

Tags: ios, drawing

I am playing around with a little drawing app I am making and was wondering how to change the "brush" like in photoshop. I would like to use custom images as the brushes rather than just a circle. How do I go about doing this?

Here is how I currently draw:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeCopy);

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);


    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentSize);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw the brush image, with proper blending, at several points along the line segment that make up a brush stroke.